# Why do we consider a wavelength range when defining spectral emissive power of a blackbody?

Tags: heat-transfer, radiation, thermal-radiation

The spectral hemispherical emissive power of a blackbody is the amount of thermal energy emitted in the form of EMW lying in the wavelength range of $\lambda$ to $\lambda + d\lambda$ via thermal radiation, per unit time, per unit area and per unit the wavelength interval $d\lambda$.

My question is why do we consider a wavelength interval? why not just a value of wavelength.

P.S.-I'm studying Thermal radiation at graduate level.

Comment: Because thermal energy emitted is not at one exact wavelength but over a range. Much like your hearing…

Answer (score 1):

Thermally radiated photons are emitted in whole piece of material, but only those photons which were born near the surface have a substantial possibility to avoid getting caught inside the piece. So this makes the radiated energy sound to be said as "per unit area".

The stream of the emitted photons doesn't occur as pulses when our observation time interval is in practically achievable scale. Thus the energy is also sound to be said as energy per unit time. That's power, so until this we have power per unit area.

The emitted photons have a huge number of possible wavelengths. A photon with energy W or as well with wavelength ch/W is emitted when some particle changes its quantum state so that the energy of the particle drops amount W.

Quantum theory shows that so many different quantum states and so many transitions between them are possible that our only way to describe the radiated power is to present the radiated energy as distribution.

Of course one could in theory build a table which tells the real discrete possible wavelengths and how many times each wavelength occurs in certain temperature, blackbody area and time interval. But that's only theory - the number of possible wavelengths is so huge that virtually any measurable wavelength range will contain some possible photon wavelengths. Some wavelengths occur more probably than others. The distribution presents that probability variation.

The well known blackbody radiation distribution presents the radiated power per unit area and per unit wavelength.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, it makes no sense to specify output at a perfectly monochromatic wavelength.  If you look at the existing formulas, you'll see the limit of output as $\Delta\lambda$ approaches zero looks like zero.